# How to efficiently tie a UDP Packet to an entity

Tags: java, sockets, udp

My application has made use of a TCP Connection up until now, but after awhile I've decided to go ahead and start sending some information through UDP Packets. The application that I'm working on is a hobbyist game project and I'm now sending the movement through UDP packets instead of TCP Packets.

The problem I'm facing is efficiently linking the UDP Packet to an Entity, in this case a User.

Here's my current setup:

- Account class has a UUID Variable
- When the TCP Client successfully connects, the TCP Server tells the Client what it's UUID is.
- The UUID is then sent as a "Header" for the UDP Packets
- When the UDP Packet is recieved by the server, the server finds the account relative to the UUID in the header, and then processes the logic accordingly.

The problem is, a UUID is a fairly large string, and this isn't very bandwidth friendly, I could just as easily use an Integer instead of a string that references an Accounts index on a `List<Account>` but the problem with that is security- This would mean that anybody could send a UDP Packet with someones account index (Respectively 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc) and perform actions on their account using this "spoofed" or fake packet.

The UUID doesn't run into this problem, while the same security issue is still in effect, it's highly unlikely for someone to know another users UUID.

What would be the best way to go about tying a Datagram packet to an account, without involving large security risks, and without destroying bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

A UUID fits into 16 bytes (two `long` primitives), so in the scheme of things I don't think you really need to be too concerned with it's size. Just don't transmit it as a string.

Comment: How exactly would it be transmitted then? You stated that it's two long primitives, let's say for example I'm using the DataOutputStream, how would I handle this. (How would I get the first long and the last long from the UUID, and then even more so, how would I use the two longs to create the UUID again)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the source address of the packet.

If you are receiving the datagrams with a `DatagramChannel`, `receive` returns the source address. If you are using a `DatagramSocket` you can get the address of a packet by calling `getSocketAddress` after you receive it.

This still isn't completely secure since someone could spoof someone else's address if they know it, although it has 0 overhead.

Comment: I rather use a little overhead than have something this easy to mess with, finding somebodies IP address isn't hard.

Comment: Well they would also need the port number, but I agree you should have more security for important things.